# How to get a function result without passing any parameters in REST API method?

Tags: php, function, rest

My function

```
public static function getArtistCount()
{
    global $DB;
    $sql =  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM tbl_artists";

    if (!$DB->Query($sql)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$rows = $DB->RecordsArray(1)) {
        return false;
    }

    $count= $rows[0]['Count'];
        return $count;
    }
```

I also have result variable to call rest and store the data

```
$result = Utility_API::callREST($params , 'Artist/get')
```

My REST service is of

```
public function get()
{
    $status = false;
    $result = array();

    if ($result = Data_Artist::getArtistCount()) {
        $status = true;
        $data = $result->toArray();
    }

    return $this->generateReturn($status, $data);
}
```

I need to know how to get the count and also need to know how to get the function result when no parameter is required or passed.

Answer (score 0):

Sending no parameters :

If your REST Service can simply handle it ,you can pass empty in `$params` .Usually,it will be an array (again,depends on the API).

```
$result = Utility_API::callREST(array() , 'Artist/get')
```

Getting Count :

Depends on output of `$this->generateReturn($status, $data)` what is it returning ? That will be captured in `$result` .

Try echo `var_dump($result)` to see what is that your getting from that call.

Also try to put echo statements whenever possible to see what is going on,Like :

```
if ($result = Data_Artist::getArtistCount()) {
        $status = true;
        echo "I am here and the result is :";
        echo var_dump($result);
        $data = $result->toArray();
        echo "This is my data!" . var_dump($result);
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: i have tried but all am getting is an empty result , as i run the query manually i am able to get the result in wamp.